# How to makefile in c programm with input txt file from another directory

Tags: c, makefile, directory

Im trying to create a makefile that executes with input from a txt file in different directory. My direcotry goes like this:

```
project/misc/input.txt
project/programms/findlines.c
```

My makefile so far is something like this:

```
# #Paths to input files
 words-10= ../../misc/words  

#compiler used
CC = gcc 

#Files .o
OBJS = find_lines.o words-10

#Executable programm
EXEC = find_lines

#Parameters
ARGS =

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(EXEC) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)

run:
    time ./find_lines < words-10

valgrind:
    valgrind ./find_lines < words-10
```

It seems that the compiler does not find the input file and projects the error "No such file existing"

Comment: What happens if you replace the line ```words-10=../../misc/words``` with ```words-10=../misc/words```?

Comment: you are right, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable substitution for `words-10` should be the same as for other variables in your makefile like `CC`, `OBJS`, and `EXEC`: you will want to replace references to `words-10` with `$(words-10)` or `${words-10}`.

In addition, you probably don't want it included in `OBJS` as it doesn't look like a file that you want to pass to `gcc` for linking.

```
# #Paths to input files
words-10= ../../misc/words  

#compiler used
CC = gcc 

#Files .o
OBJS = find_lines.o

#Executable programm
EXEC = find_lines

#Parameters
ARGS =

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(EXEC) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)

run:
    time ./find_lines < $(words-10)

valgrind:
    valgrind ./find_lines < $(words-10)
```

Comment: I don't think `${words-10}` (with curly brackets) can be used for makefile variables (unless they have been exported to the environment).

Comment: @IanAbbott Please see [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html): `Macros can appear anywhere in the makefile. Macro expansions using the forms $(string1) or ${ string1} shall be replaced by string2`.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT: Here is the solution finaly,thank you all for your help!

fileswords-10 = ../../misc/words #Paths to input

CC = gcc #compiler used

OBJS = find_lines.o #Files .o

EXEC = find_lines #Executable program

ARGS = $(words-10)/words-10 #Parameters

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(EXEC)

clean:
rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)

run:
time ./$(EXEC) < $(ARGS)

valgrind:
valgrind ./find_lines < $(ARGS)